# Add member to struct that is inherited from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

In the oversimplified example below, `class Derived` inherits private members/methods from `class Base`. What I would like to do is to be able to add an additional member (`double salary`) to the inherited struct in the Derived class.

```
struct Person {
  int age;
  int height;
};

class Base {
  protected:
     Person worker;
  public:
     double hours (Person *employee);
};

class Derived: public Base {
  private:
    //Class has an inherited member named "Person worker"
    //How do I add new member "double salary" to struct "Person worker"
    double salary (Person *manager); //A method that will rely on "double salary" 
};
```

Perhaps something like this (as suggested by Vlad below) would work but is there a better way?

```
struct Person {
  int age;
  int height;
};

struct Person2: Person {
  double salary;
}

class Base {
  private:
     Person worker;

  public:
     double hours (Person *employee);
};

class Derived: public Base {
  private:
    Person2 fulltime;
    double salary (Person2 *manager); //A method that will rely on "double salary" 
};
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but `Person worker` is still inherited by the derived class except that it cannot be directly accessed (but the `hours` method, which is also inherited, has access to it because it is a part of the base class).

Comment: plain curiosity: could you explain what the `hours` method does?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: It's a fictitious example but the hours method, say, returns the number of hours that an employee works. The base class can be for a general worker and the derived class can be for a full-time manager with a salary instead of hourly pay.

Comment: Can't you make worker protected. Or add a getter function to Base?

Comment: why do you have to pass a Person? The base class already contains one.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Again, since it is a fictitious example, the number of hours that is returned depends on, say, another person's age/height. I understand that it sounds funny but the focus of the question is how to add a new member to the struct from a derived class while being able to inherit (struct)members/methods from the base class.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Can you explain why this question is "off-topic"? There is a library that I am using and I would like to extend the class through inheritance. However, the base class contains a struct that I would like to add a member to but don't understand how to.  When I say "fictitious example", I am referring to the example given but my actual code encompasses the same problem and follows the "question checklist" of a "as a short but complete program" to get the point through. Please enlighten me. If I can modify my question then I would be happy to.

Comment: @drescherjm: In reality, there are many functions that I would like to inherit from the base class. For simplicity, only one function is shown. But the real question is whether it is possible to add a member to the struct in the derived class. And, if not, how can I work around this since I would like to extend the base class.

Comment: Yes you can extend the base class with member functions that use the Person struct however since worker is private you need to either make it protected or provide a getter function so that the Derived class has access to worker.

Comment: @drescherjm: Thanks, you were right. The Person struct should have been protected. I've corrected it now. However, can you suggest how I can add a member to the Person struct for the derived class? Or, should I leave the Person struct as private in the base class (so that the Person struct cannot be accessed but the methods are inherited) and then define a new, derived struct (as suggested below) to be used in the derived class?

Comment: If you need to add a member to the Person class then I believe you need to do what Vlad from Moscow said in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly You need to introduce one more class in the hierarhy. For example

```
struct Employee : Person
{
    double salary;
};
```

Comment: I still want to be able to inherit the method (hours) and member (employee) from the base class. Maybe it isn't clear to me but doesn't using this hierarchy mean that I would add this struct as a member to the derived class but not actually inherit any of the members/methods from the base class? Perhaps you can clarify.

Comment: You can not to add data member to class Person other than to introduce one more level of the hierarchy.